# How to Detect state change in database table and add a schedule function to run at a specific time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

Let’s say I have a website where users can create questionnaires(Surveys) that get stored in the database for their users to answers the questions. My idea was to send an email notification to their users when the questionnaire has been changed for example a new question being added to the questionnaire.

However, to avoid send email every two minutes in case the user keeps on editing the questionnaire, I have created a temporary table ("LoggedSurveyUpdate") which will keep a record on when the questionnaire has been edited.  Now the challenge that I am facing is that I would like the email notification to be sent an hour after the last questionnaire has been edited.
I hope this made sense.

```
     [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(SurveyVM vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                bool readyToPublish = false;
                if (vm.Survey.Publish)
                {
                    readyToPublish = surveyLogic.CheckIfReadyToPublish(vm.Survey);
                    if (readyToPublish)
                    {
                       // User currentUser = userLogic.GetBy(x => x.UserID == vm.User.UserID);
                        Survey survey = surveyLogic.GetBy(x => x.SurveyName == vm.Survey.SurveyName && x.CustomerID == vm.Survey.CustomerID && x.SurveyID != vm.Survey.SurveyID).SingleOrDefault();
                        if (survey == null)
                        {
                            surveyLogic.Update(vm.Survey);


                           surveyLogic.SuveyUpdate(vm.Survey);
                        }

            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                vm.CategoryOptions = CategoryOptionsHelper.BuildCategoryOptions(vm.Survey.CustomerID, false);
                TempData["Failure"] = "Edit Failed. Please Review Your Selections and Try Again.";
                return View(vm);
            }
```

}
}

> Where data gets inserted in temporary table

```
      public void SuveyUpdate(Survey survey)
    {
        using (ManageLoggedSurveyUpdate updateLogic = new ManageLoggedSurveyUpdate(ref base.Uow))
        using (ManageSurvey surveyLogic = new ManageSurvey(ref base.Uow))
        using (ManageLoggedSurveyUpdate loggedSurveyUpdate = new ManageLoggedSurveyUpdate(ref base.Uow))
        {
            Survey surveys = surveyLogic.GetBy(x => x.SurveyID == survey.SurveyID && x.Publish == survey.Publish).SingleOrDefault();

            if (surveys == null)
            {
                LoggedSurveyUpdate newupdte = new LoggedSurveyUpdate()
                {
                    SurveyID = survey.SurveyID,
                    Active = true,
                    SurveyEdited = DateTime.Now,
                    UserID = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"],



                };
                loggedSurveyUpdate.Insert(newupdte);
            }
            else {

                LoggedSurveyUpdate newupdte = new LoggedSurveyUpdate()
                {

                    SurveyID = survey.SurveyID,
                    Active = true,
                    SurveyEdited = DateTime.Now,
                    UserID = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"],




                };

                loggedSurveyUpdate.Update(newupdte);


            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: Create a (windows) service that polls the table on a set schedule.

Comment: @Igor any idea on how to this suggestion

Comment: Google [c# how to create a windows service](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+how+to+create+a+windows+service)